# Can't write to my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have been toying around with PHP and MySQL for a while now, but I can't get this to work.

I have the following two code snippets.

From index.php:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <label>
        <p class="tekst">Nu kommer det svære valg! Skal det være: <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="Tur" id="Tur1" value="Tur1">Tur 1?<br />
        </label> 
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Tur" id="Tur2" value="Tur2">Tur 2?</p>
        </label> <br />
        <center> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="turSvar()">Jeg er klar til gåtur!</button> </center> <br/> <br/>
    </form>
```

and send.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['Tur'])){
        $Tur = $_POST['Tur'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO whatever VALUES ($Tur)");
    }
```

I have already created a table called "whatever" in my database (managed through phpMyAdmin). If I use the editor in phpMyAdmin to insert a string to the whatever table, it works. So is there a mistake in any of my code? I use mysqli_connect to connect to the database.

Any help would be nice!

Comment: Have you tried echoing the query itself, to see if it's being created correctly? Also, are you sure $_POST["Tur"] is set? The form in the html snippet has no submit button, but rather a button that has an onclick function; what does it do? Are you sure the form data is being sent? I suspect that's where the problem lies

Comment: do you get an error from MySQL?

Comment: is your table composed of one column really?

Comment: I think you're right Michael Beeson. I'm still new to everything related to web development, so I think it's definitely there the problem lies.
I just added a Submit button, and now when I press it I get redirected to "send.php".. Which is a start I guess :)

Comment: As Hilmi says, this relies on only having a single column in the table (its very bad practice to make assumptions like this - and also implies bad data design). It also assumes that the user will submit a numeric value. Further you really should read up on SQL injection.

Comment: There's no post field called `Tur`

Comment: Turn error reporting on!

Comment: Why do you mix mysqli with mysql??? Use `mysqli_connect()` AND `mysqli_query()` or the ancient and deprecated `mysql_connect()` AND `mysql_query()`!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to create a connexion to the database first in order to interact (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, etc.) with it:

```
$conn = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_password );
```

Now select the database:

```
mysql_select_db( $db_name );
```

**Please since you are beginning read : [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**

Comment: OP says he uses `mysqli_connect` already

Comment: Thanks, but I still see `mysql_query` in his question.